# neo4j batch-import node count

Tags: import, neo4j

i have a csv file with 1845554 lines, each representing a node, but using the batch-import ( https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/ ) the result is

```
.........
Importing 924693 Nodes took 1270 seconds

Importing 3014 Relationships took 0 seconds
........
Total import time: 1286 seconds
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: id=927736
```

all subsequent import fails due to the importer not finding all nodes...
any hints why ?

just as a side note, the file is 1.9GB large.

thank you.

Comment: no one had this problem ? how can i proceed with this ? thanks ...

Comment: you have wrong node-id's in your relationships-file, you only have `924693` nodes but refer to id `927736` which is much higher.

Comment: i thought that each line in the csv would be a new node ? 924693 nodes are imported, but there is 1845554 lines in the csv (using wc -l file.csv). i was expecting it to import 1845553 nodes...

Comment: Then something else is off, perhaps unusual line-breaks or quotes? Try to use the "safe" opencsv based reader, by configuring: `batch_import.csv.quotes=true`

Comment: can you check the lines around 924693 ?